# Editing header links in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, header, toplinks

I'm on Magento 2.1, the header links are rendered with this structure:

```
<ul class="header links">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I need to remove the class `.header` from `<ul>` tag and add another ones.

Also, I need to add some HTML inside `<li>` tags.

How can do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can change `css_class` class **"header links"** by following

In default theme you can change or if you have specific theme you change there.

/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

If you want to add extra links ( Taken from customer module ). you can use below code in you `layout` by your `block` classes

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
           template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Need to create block for `href=""`

/vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/Link.php

```
public function getHref()
{
    return "http://example.com/";
}
```

You can add html by the referencing `<referenceContainer name="header.panel">`

> I have added code from core modules for reference. recommended to
>   override by creating new module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

after added this code top.links not showing