# How to change the links of header menu in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, header, toplinks

`How to change the links of this this menu

[image: Register here]

**Register here links** in my account menu

any ideas

Comment: follow this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129951/editing-header-links-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the `default.xml` in your theme : `app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Here you can add or remove the header top link as:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!--  you can easly add New links with following code -->
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
               <!-- Contact us Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Constact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <!-- CMS Page Link Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="aboutus.link" after="contactus.link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">about-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

             <!--  you can easly Remove  links with following code -->
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->

        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Seems to work removing links, but adding links like so does not seem to work....